# How does SCIP calculate vanillafullstrongbranching-scores?

Tags: scip

I want to do some experiments on branchingrules in SCIP (using the python interface).
To be sure some basics of my code work, I tried to mirror the vanillafullstrongbranching of SCIP using the dive functionality.
This works mostly as expected, but I get weird results for nodes that have at least one infeasible child. I dug through PySCIPOpt and the C-code of SCIP and would have expected a big number as the sb score in case (at least) one child is infeasible, as the LP-solver returns a big number for infeasible problems and SCIP is using the product-score by default. Instead of  big numbers I get numbers just big enough to be bigger than the other scores.
My questions is: What am I missing in the code? Where and how does SCIP treat the score for infeasible children differently.

As quite some code is required to reproduce this, I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/CharJon/cd7326d3645c34b342a6e64f474f147b), that makes use of a set-cover instance I also uploaded to github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the strongbranching score never exceeds the cutoffbound of the lp, so infeasible nodes would get a score of the cutoffbound.

Comment: Hi @Leon, thanks for your reply. This sounds reasonable and I will check if the scores match. If you happen to know where in the SCIP code I missed this important detail, please let me know.

Comment: It is in `SCIPcolGetStrongbranch`, after you call `SCIPlpiStrongbranch...` in the `else` case.